# React-Native navigation with Stack Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation with combination of tab navigator and stack navigator. How can i now weather stack of stack navigator is empty or contains some values

```
  componentWillMount() {
   var self=this; 
   BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      console.log("Props",self.props);
      if(stack of stack navigator has data){
        navigate to Screen required
      }else{
        close the app
      }
   })
   componentWillUnmount() {
     var self=this;
     BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',self.backNav());
   }
   backNav(){
    console.log("Navigating Back");
    return false;
   }
```

[image: Response of props]

Answer (score 0):

Reading the official GitHub repo I discovered an issue asking for that [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/455).

So basically It should look like this:

```js
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
    if(this.props.navigation.state.routes[0].index === 0) 
      return false; //Prevent closing the app

    navigation.goBack(); 

    return true;
})
```

BTW, I'm just curious: why are you using `self` rather that `this`?

Additionally, and also important, take a look at [this](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2023).

Comment: `BTW, I'm just curious: why are you using self rather that this?` - `this` reference is lost in a function. Only arrow functions preserve `this`. But I presume that since its in component `this` should also work.

Comment: You can always bind your functions manually, but as you have said, &#39;this&#39; should work since it is a component. 
Did it work?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca as you mention, if condition does not match with response of props. Please find attached image for response

Comment: @Sau_Patil how are you injecting the navigator in your mainRoot component?

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate("AccountList");

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to mean that. Take a look at @lndgalante comment on that issue.